# Enabling search on attachment names for email documents archived through IBM Content Collector

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-collector

We need to be able to search on email attachment names (Name of the files attached to an email archived in FileNet through IBM ICC Microsoft Exchange email connector)

If we just enable CBR on the object store, we are able to search the text in attachment body but not the attachment names.

Another approach we thought of is to save the attachment names in a metadata property. But issue here is, we are not able to extract the attachment names in ICC. Please suggest any approach for this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check the filename in the content element of created document for attachment.

If the filename contains the original attachment name, you can copy this value into DocumentName property throught handler action or pre-processor action.